# Enhanced for loops

Tags: java, foreach

So I'm looking at one of my examples in java course and instead of using a regular for loop an enhanced for loop was used. I've been trying to change it back to a regular for loop but have had no luck. I've looked through the similar questions but was unable to figure it out. can someone point me in the right direction.

```
int total = 0;
int i;

// loop through homeworks, add to total
for(Integer grade: this.homeworks){         
  total = total + grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enhanced for loop in Java is just short hand for a regular for loop there is  no performance difference between the 2.

Here's a few different variants you could use:

```
    List<Integer> homework = new ArrayList<>();
    homework.add(new Integer(6));
    homework.add(new Integer(7));
    homework.add(new Integer(8));
    homework.add(new Integer(9));

    for (Integer integer : homework) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

    for (Iterator<Integer> it = homework.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Integer integer = it.next();
        System.out.println(integer);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < homework.size(); i++) {
        Integer integer = homework.get(i);
        System.out.println(integer);

    }
```

Comment: I tried your variations however it isn't pulling anything from the ArrayList for some reason.

Comment: I've updated the example to include 4 elements in the list and print them.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that enhanced for loop is efficient than normal for loop.

Actually sometimes its less efficient for the program, but most of the time its exactly the same.

Its more efficient for the developer, which is often far more important

A for-each loop is particularly useful when iterating over a collection.

```
List<String> list = 
for(Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); list.hasNext(); ) {
    String s = list.next();
   ------
 }
```

is more easily written as (but does the same thing as, so its no more efficient for the program)

```
   List<String> list = 
    for(String s: list) {
      ---
}
```

Using the "old" loop is slightly more efficient when access a randomly accessible collection by index.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // implements RandomAccess
for(int i=0, len = list.size(); i < len; i++) // doesn't use an Iterator!
```

Using a for-each loop on a collection always uses an Iterator which is slightly less efficient for random access lists.

use a for-each loop is never more efficient for the program, but like I said the efficiency of the developer is often *far more important*.